# How to read DOM in React

Tags: javascript, css, dom, reactjs

React is uni-directional.

However, there are many cases where we need to 'get' / read DOM, whether it is to get the parent element / or CSS values.

In my case, I have a dynamic width property set on a div, which I want to get in absolute units (px), how does React handle this kind of logic? I have come across suggestions of using 'refs' in React, however, I am not clear whether that is the recommended method.

```
CSS:
...
width: 60%;
...
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about using refs, you could also do it with native javascript dom querys but setting a ref for a element is faster.

So basically you set a ref like this:

```
<div ref="awesome"></div>
```

Then in your code do something like:

```
var node = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.awesome);
alert(node.offsetWidth);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in React v14.0, findDOMNode became part of the React-DOM package. This means you have to use ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.awesome); Another note which can be added this in most cases findDOMNode is unnecessary in React 14.0 and you can just use this.refs.awesome. See https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html and the part about DOM node refs

Comment: On [React's official pages on refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-returned-from-reactdom.render), they mention that string based refs like above is "mostly legacy at this point", and apparently prefer callback based refs. I still use string, but should this could be useful to pointn out.